# jquery swap or move elements between 3 or more divs

Tags: jquery, html, move

My script:

```
$(function () {
     initSwap();

     function initSwap() {
         initDroppable($(".dropdiv img,.dragdiv img"));
         initDraggable($(".dragdiv img,.dropdiv img"));
     }

     function initDraggable($elements) {
         $elements.draggable({
             appendTo: "body",
             tolerance: "pointer",
             helper: "clone",
             revert: "invalid"
         });
     }

     function initDroppable($elements) {
         $elements.droppable({
             appendTo: "body",
             activeClass: "ui-state-default",
             hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
             accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",

             over: function (event, ui) {
                 var $this = $(this);
             },
             drop: function (event, ui) {
                 var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                 var draggablePlace = ui.draggable.attr("place");

                 var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
                 var droppablePlace = $(this).attr("place");

                 var $this = $(this);
                 var linew1 = $(this).after(ui.draggable.clone());
                 var linew2 = $(ui.draggable).after($(this).clone());

                 $(ui.draggable).remove();
                 $(this).remove();
                 initSwap();
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

I made a jsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/kehator/7bZrV/23/](http://jsfiddle.net/kehator/7bZrV/2/)

It works almost perfect, but I need one more thing to do with 
`<div id="container" class="container">`

I would like to store the elements of the container so that the boxes may be empty, and replacement parts were made only after moving one element to another

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5BgL.jpg

Comment: So you mean you want the source box to appear empty while dragging the image, instead of having the ghost image of it until the switch is made?

Comment: I want to swich elements between boxex and container and move elements from boxes to container (then boxes are empty) and elements in container can be sorted.

Comment: just how to move now element from box to container without clone (box empty) help! :(